# Cat2Vec embedding a categorical value columns with respect to multiple y's

Tags: word-embeddings

I try to do some embeddings on categorical columns using Keras. Here is the code:

```
embedding_size = 7
model = k.models.Sequential()
model.add(k.layers.Embedding(input_dim = 13, output_dim = embedding_size, input_length = 1, name="embedding"))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(50, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(15, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss = "mse", optimizer = "adam", metrics=["accuracy"])
model.fit(x = df['Release Cause'].as_matrix(), y=df['Jitter'].as_matrix() , epochs = 50, batch_size = 4)
```

Here `y` is only one column of the dataset. I want to do embedding with respect to multiple columns. Is it possible and how to achieve it.

Comment: Welcome to the community. 
At present your question is a bit unclear. You may add a few lines of your dataset with features and targets you are talking about. I think you want to do categorical encoding based on multiple targets, is that right?

Comment: @TwinPenguins yes that is exactly what I need. In the code the target is only df['Jitter'] but say I want to add more value say df['ANR'], df['duration']

Comment: OK. let me ask you this. If this was regression how would be solve it? Could you combine all targets or had to train three regression for each target? From this intuition, I do not think there is a straightforward way of just passing multiple targets and encode a categorical variable. To be best of my knowledge, you should do it separately and somehow take the mean (for example) of the encoded variable for the three targets. Share if you find something else.

Comment: @TwinPenguins I am working on subscriber anomaly detection on telecom data...in initial and  experimenting.. cant share the data-set due to privacy reasons. I  am doing  clustering first. have  categorical columns in the dataseset. Now I am trying to to some embedding on dataset based on other columns of dataset.  I just need embedding to input into my clustering model. I did it with One Hot Encoding but I am trying some better methods too. I want my categorical data to be embedded based on multiple features on my dataset so that it can relate better. Hope you understand my problem.

Comment: @TwinPenguins Sorry If I got you confused at first. I am pretty new to data science and learning. Its not actually target but trying to embed categorical value based on multiple other features/params of my dataset. Its not a labelled data I am trying to do clustering and based on that will do some labeling and proceed ahead

Comment: About data sharing. When I suggested posting part of your data, I did not mean you need to actually post your confidential information. You can always post a dummy form of your data to convey your message easier. 
About your problem: I see. So you do no have any target (labels or dependent variable). As far as I know methods like Entity Embedding that are proposed to encode cat to vec can not be used in an unsupervised fashion. Unless your categories carry a particular semantic as in Languages you may use pretrained model from NLP like Glove to convert which is rare.

Comment: You may try other methods other than OHE if this is what you want to experiment. Methods like Hashing, Binary Encoding etc. exists. But for this purpose, if your categorical variable is not complex (it is not high cardinal), OHE still is a good choice. I may ask you actually, how do you evaluate the quality of your clusters? How is based on human judgement or there is an actual metric in place? If it is human-dependent it would be quite subjective, and the choice of your encoding method would not matter that much! This is a general challenge for most of unsupervised methods. Good luck.

Comment: @TwinPenguins: Cant I use cat2vec to embed my catogorial data based on some other independent variables in my dataset instead of some labels. Is it a wrong approach to do. For One hot what should be the maximum cardinality.